# How to setup environment variables with behave (Python BDD framework)?

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, python-behave, rubypython

So our test environments dynamically change depending on the release that we are working on.

For example:

- for abc release the URL for the test environment would be feature-abc.mycompany.com, for xyz release the URL for the test environment would be feature-xyz.company.com and so on so forth.
- Same thing would be for staging: release-abc.mycompany.com, release-xyz.mycompany.com, etc..
- Production is just static URL: platform.mycompany.com

With this being said, I need to specify on which URL I would like my tests to be executed using behave BDD framework for Python.

To be specific Im looking for the equivalent functionality that cucumber has for Ruby using: features/support/env.rb file to define multiple URL (qa, staging, production, etc) so that on the command-line (terminal) I would just say xyz (having qa = feature(the release).mycompany.com

Something like: [How can I test different environments (e.g. development|test|production) in Cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368625/how-can-i-test-different-environments-e-g-developmenttestproduction-in-cucu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so for this there is a Pull Request (PR #243) to be able to do this in behave's github repo.

In the meantime as a workaround they suggested me to use `os.getenv('variable_name', 'default_value')`, and then at the command line I would just say `export variable_name='another_value' ; behave`

Please see more detailed on this on our short thread:

https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/250

Answer (score 1):

behave-1.2.5 introduced the [userdata](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.6.html?highlight=userdata#tagged-examples-with-active-tags-and-userdata) concept.

```
behave -D BUILD_STAGE=develop …
```

Load the corresponding configuration for this stage in the `before_all()` hook.

Comment: The provided link is dead.